# How to send base64 image via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, base64

I am develop t-shirt constructor. When I send base64 data (`canvas.toDataUrl()`) via ajax POST method to server, I get base64 string with spaces.

For exmaple:

Send:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAhsAAAIbCAYAAABCJ1y9AAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9CbCmVXkuur7pn/bcczd00w2INAhBmdQ4EDNpHEi8gVMQcyKpc3NOck3lOKRyokmFUzmHSupgLG9MTFKpeK
```

Get:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAhsAA 
 AIbCAYAAABCJ1y9AAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9CbCmVXkuur7pn/b 
 cczd00w2INAhBmdQ4EDNpHEi8gVMQcyKpc3 NOck3lOKRyokmFUzmH SupgLG9MT   FKpeK
```

JS code:

```
var data = csrfParam + '=' + csrfToken + '&front_base64=' + frontImage
     + '&back_base64=' + backImage + '&product_id=' + currentProduct['id'] 
     + '&color_id=' + currentProductColorId + '&size_id=' + 
     currentProductSize;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', '/constructor/add-to-cart/', true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send(data);
 xhr.onload = function () {console.log(xhr.responseText)}
```

[white spacing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM1AG.png)

Comment: Are the spaces showing in the request data? If you go under the developer console->network tab and look at the request, do the spaces show up there? If so, then that is an issue with javascript adding them, not PHP. You could also try using `encodeURIComponent()` around your variables to make sure that url entities are converted properly to their url escaped values (ie `%20` for spaces). If you still see the spaces, you would need to provide more code as what is shown here wouldn't do that.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` not convert url escaped values. But when i write front_base64 to txt file in server I see spaces

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ajax it will make your life a lot easier and the problem will be solved as well :

```
$.post('/constructor/add-to-cart/',{
      csrfParam : csrfToken,
      front_base64: frontImage,
      back_base64 : backImage,
      product_id : currentProduct['id'],
      color_id  : currentProductColorId,
      size_id : currentProductSize
    },function(response){
     console.log(response)
    });
```

and if you want view the base64 image in backend to check if its ok

```
<img src="/* base 64 string here */" />
```

rather then just viewing the string.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood my problem, I need to add `encodeURIComponent()` around base64. Thanks Jonathan Kuhn for help!