# How to save very long string via web api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api which takes a string as the content.

The problem is, the content may include an image (which has a base64 value), for example.

```
<div contenteditable="false" style="">Left Yipee... And again, another edit.
    <img id="addedImage_0" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Sr8RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAA8BAgAJAA.......Wf/Z" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
</div>
```

I'm trying to save that entire HTML into a database but for now, more keen on just getting it to post using AJAX

When I don't have the image in the content, then it posts and saves perfectly.

I don't understand what the actual issue is... is it due to the length of the string because I assume the computer is seeing the base64 as a string?

Comment: Please check if it help you to do it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599205/how-to-send-base64-image-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I saw [How to send base64 image via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599205/how-to-send-base64-image-via-ajax) thanks to Allen Skywalker, I feel that the better option is to simply treat it as the string it is... And save it in chunks (eg, save the first 1000 characters, then the next etc until no more characters are left).

This also provides a nice easy way to show a progress bar as I know how many chunks I've got and how many I've gone through.

It did mean updating the web API to be able to append