# Sending image to PHP code through ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I implemented form and I need to send Image to PHP function.. but is does not work.  Did I implement correct selector for my picture?

```
var photoAdvertisement = $("#pro-img-4").attr('src');
    // get values to an array()
    var requestArray = "";

    requestArray = {"name" : $("#nameAdvertisement").val(),
    "category" : $("#categoryAdvertisement").val(),
    "description" : $("#descriptionAdvertisement").val(),
    "photoAdvertisement" : $("#pro-img-4").attr('src')};


    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {"action": "addAdvertisement", "formValidation": requestArray},
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {

            console.log("data: "+data);
        }
    });
```

Picture of my HTML class and ID with picture

[image]

It returned me long string in similar like that => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3A . Please, is that correct way ?

Comment: A base64-encoded image that starts with `data:image` in the `src` attribute should render correctly.

Comment: " but is does not work" What does not work exactly? You are reading the attribute and it is giving you the base64 code, is it having issues with the post?

Comment: that Image String is send to PHP for adding picture to My Post in Wordpress, do I have to parse that incoming long string to the some different way? Or this string is correct and should cause adding picture ?

Comment: Check out these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867591/post-sending-base64-image-with-ajax and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599205/how-to-send-base64-image-via-ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047648/how-to-post-an-image-in-base64-encoding-via-ajax